# Scroll on my div after click button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Helo,

I have a button that displays a div after clicking this button.
But after trying many combinations of jQuery, I can not ensure that once the button clicked, the page will automatically scroll the div available while that appears.

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var job = $("#job");
    var open = $("#open");

    job.hide();

    open.click(function() {
        job.slideDown();
        $(this).fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#job").hide();
 $('#urBtn').on('click', function(){
     if (!$("#job").is(':visible')){
       $("#job").fadeOut();
     }
 });
```